# Why does my call to `stringWithFormat:` crash my program?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, osx-mavericks

I am trying to use the following format string, but it causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` trying to read at `0xC` from `objc_msgSend`. Clang tells me the format string is valid (aside that it has unused arguments). Here is an SSCCE:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString* segment = nil;
        NSString* base = @"ebp";
        char sign = '+';
        long long displacement = 12;
        long long absDisplacement = llabs(displacement);
        NSString* offset = nil;
        NSString* nsSize = @"dword";

        NSString* r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%7$@ ptr [%2$@ %3$c %5$lli]", segment, base, sign, displacement, absDisplacement, offset, nsSize];
        NSLog(@"%@", r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't use all the arguments for the format string because the specific format is to be selected out of 16 possibilities, and some arguments aren't used in all format strings (this specific format string ignores parameters 1, 4 and 6). The types are as follows:

1. `NSString*`
2. `NSString*`
3. `char`
4. `long long`
5. `long long`
6. `NSString*`
7. `NSString*`

And as far as I can tell, all my format specifiers respect that. No printed object argument is nil, even though this is a supported scenario of `stringWithFormat:`.

So what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Changing the value of `displacement` changes the faulty read address, but I can't see why. The format string still looks right to me... I can't figure out the pattern either: 12 crashes at 0xc, 13 crashes at 0x18, 14 crashes at 0xe, 15 crashes at 0x18, 16 crashes at 0x10, 17 causes the program to exit with a status of zero without going through `NSLog`.

Comment: `long long` values occupy two positions in the parameter list.  So your first reference is grabbing the second half of absDisplacement.

Comment: The reason is probably similar to that, but I'm somewhat surprised that on a 64 bits machine a long long is 2 positions.

Comment: @HotLicks It also breaks with a 32bit type like int.

Comment: It has to be that way for compatibility.  Only one of the two parm list slots is used, but both are allocated.  (Or, actually, I think the same value is loaded into both slots.)

Comment: It breaks if BOTH the long longs are changed to ints?

Comment: Mac OS X completely changed its vararg calling convention between the 32 bits ABI and the 64 bits ABI, so I doubt it's for compatibility reasons. I'll try for the kicks though.

Comment: This isn't about vararg, it's about C-language standards.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes. See my answer and edit, it uses `long long`, but doesn't crash and outputs the expected result (`dword ptr [ebp + 12]`)

Comment: I can also testify that it still doesn't work if you change both arguments to integers. (EDIT: you can't change unused NSString* pointers to "just" integers though, so that might be part of the reason)

Comment: Then presumably the other answers are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is in the man page (emphasis mine):

> An optional field, consisting of a decimal digit string followed by a
>   $, specifying the next argument to access.  If this field is not
>   provided, the argument following the last argument accessed will be
>   used.  Arguments are numbered starting at 1.  **If unaccessed
>   arguments in the format string are interspersed with ones that are
>   accessed the results will be indeterminate**.

Edit: Here is the working version with unused parameters stripped:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* segment = nil;
        NSString* base = @"ebp";
        char sign = '+';
        long long displacement = 12;
        long long absDisplacement = llabs(displacement);
        NSString* offset = nil;
        NSString* nsSize = @"dword";

        NSString* r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4$@ ptr [%1$@ %2$c %3$lli]", base, sign, absDisplacement, nsSize];
        NSLog(@"%@", r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't omit some arguments in a format string. This is because of how C varargs work — the arguments list is essentially just a stream of indiscriminate bytes. In order to read argument 5, the function needs to know the types of arguments 1-4 to figure out where argument 5 is in the list.